# sudo a2enmod ssl - error message

Tags: 16.04, apache2, ssl

Does this mean a2enmod is failing to install? Anyone know of a fix?
 Thanks [image: a2enmod]

Comment: Have you configured and installed a valid SSL certificate on the system such that Apache can access and use it? Have you configured Apache to use that certificate? Does Apache have permission to read the certificate files? Enabling SSL on Apache is more complicated than just enabling the module.

Comment: Also, check the apache log files in `/var/log/apache2/` particularly `error.log`

Comment: This and the following question seem to be duplicates. They're by the same user, about the same problem, within a few hours of each other:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001892/curl-http-localhost-curl-l-127-0-01-not-working-for-apache-server-creation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [curl http://localhost, curl -l 127.0.01 not working for apache server creation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001892/curl-http-localhost-curl-l-127-0-01-not-working-for-apache-server-creation)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your output, it would appear that you don't have SSL configured correctly. Configuring SSL is a fairly lengthy process, and the best way to answer that is to provide a good tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-with-a-free-signed-ssl-certificate-on-a-vps

Also, the actual Apache2 docs could be useful to you:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html